# reclassify a list of strings JAVA

Tags: java, linked-list

I need some help with this Java code

I have this list saved in a text file as the following :

```
a b
a c
a d
c h
b e
b f
b g
g l
e i
e j
f k
k m
1 2
1 3
2 4
```

After reading the file test.txt, the lines are added to a list ( named ch in the code) are composed of two parts, the fist part is a source that is extracted as the variable src in the code 
The second part is a target extract as trg in the code

For instance, in the first line : a b  the source (src) is a et the target (trg) is b

NOW, I want to create a new list (myList in the code) when there is another line where the target is equal to a source of previous line. For instance, let's stay with the fist line and see the 5th line :

```
a b 
b e
```

The new list which myList must contain a line as : a b e

So in general the ch list must be reclassified as the following :

```
a d
a c h
a b g l 
a b e i 
a b e j 
a b f k m
1 2 4
1 3
```

I obtain the following exception :

> line:a b Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at pathcreator.test.main(test.java:48) Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:
>   -Xmx512M

This code is not working properly basicly because I am building only a new list with 3 elements  myList.add(src[a] +" "+trg[a]+" "+trg[b]); while it's could be more.

Any help?

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;

    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

                FileReader fis;
                fis = new FileReader("c:\\test.txt");

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fis);
                String i=null;
                String line =null;  
                String[] src = null; 
                String[] trg = null;

                 LinkedList<String> ch = new LinkedList<String>();
                 LinkedList<String> myList = new LinkedList<String>();
                try {
                    while((i = in.readLine()) != null)
                    {

                            line = i;
                            ch.add(line);

                            System.out.println(" line:"  + line);
                            src = new String[ch.size()];
                            trg =  new String[ch.size()];


                            for(int j = 0; j<ch.size()-1;j++){

                                  String pC = ch.get(j).toString();
                                  String[] pE = pC.split(" ");
                                  src[j] = pE[0];
                                  trg[j] = pE[1];     

                            }

                            for(int a = 0; a<src.length; a++){
                                for(int b = a; b<trg.length; b++){
                                    if(src[b].equals(trg[a]) && a!= b){
                                        myList.add(src[a] +" "+trg[a]+" "+trg[b]);

                                        System.out.println(src[a] +" "+trg[a]+" "+trg[b]);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            }
                        }


                catch (IOException e){
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    System.exit(1);
                }

            }

    }
```

Comment: What's the criteria behind this algorithm? What do you mean with reclassify? Also, you should post the exact *exception stacktrace* in order to let us to understand the problem.

Comment: I don't get what're trying to do.. neither from the description nor from the code. What I can tell you so far is that you're violating usual coding conventions: variables start with lowercase letters, classes start with uppercase ones (which makes it harder for me to understand it as well). But forget about the code: Could you explain the purpose of it in different words again?

Comment: @AlessandroSuglia srry for that, I added more details, thank you in advance.

Comment: @tilois I edited the questions please take a look and thank you in advance

Comment: @Volune hit the nail with his answer. I think you data structure is inappropiate for solving the problem in general. What you actualy trying to do is to find all transitive paths which result from your initial setup. Solving this with 4 lists.. while won't say it's impossible... it might be hard ;)

Comment: thanks to @Volume, alghorithms of printing roof-to-leaf paths would be useful ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem:

> The input is a list of edges of a graph,
>   The output is the list of all the roof-to-leaf paths of all trees in the graph.

I recommend to fill a graph structure with your input, then search for and use an algorithm to print roof-to-leaf paths (You can probably find one on google/stackoverflow).

Your exception is because of `j<ch.size()-1`, which leaves the last element of `Src` and `Trg` null. Try `j<ch.size()`.

Finally, please **don't use unintelligible abbreviations for variable names**, avoid `Trg`, `ch`, `pE`, ...

Comment: You get my compliment for getting the root of the problem from the initial description!

Comment: @Volume thank you ever so much you are the best, it is about finding printing  roof-to-leaf paths, found some alghorithms already and gonna work on that.